# why am i getting red underlining under url.openConnection()

Tags: java, android-studio

I'd like to know what makes my `url.openConnection` getting error.
 The error is:

> unhandled exception

Here is the code:

```
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.loginbtn:
        String link;
        String username = uname.getText().toString();
        String password = upass.getText().toString();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            String u = "http://127.0.0.1/android/login.php";
            URL url = new URL(u);
            String urlParams = "username="+username+"&password"+password;

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Let the IDE autocomplete the error fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to catch the IOException

```
... finally {
 try {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
} catch (IOException ioex) {   }
```